# Spring MVC testframework fails with HTTP Response 406

Tags: java, spring, testing, model-view-controller

I started to use the new MVC Testframework of Spring 3.2 and got stuck with getting 406 HTTP Response Codes for all my test cases.

The testcase is plain simple

```
public class LocationResouceTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetLocationByPlzPattern() throws Exception {
        // here I need to define the media type as a static var from MediaType
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/someurl?someparam=somevalue")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

the corresponding resource is

```
@Controller
// here I need to define the media type as string
@RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public class LocationResource {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList<DTO> getAllIndex(@RequestParam("someparam") String param) {
        return ... //the list of DTO classes is transformed to json just fine if called with curl
    }

}
```

I am sure it is because of a wrong media type but I cannot figure out why.

The trace of the failing testcase:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:546)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
>     at
>   de.yourdelivery.rest.location.LocationResouceTest.testGetLocationByPlzPattern(LocationResouceTest.java:37)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Answer (score 21):

If you have a `@Configuration` class, you can add the 
`@EnableWebMvc`
annotation instead of using an XML configuration with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: Thanks, adding @EnableWebMvc to my Test `@Configuration` class did the trick!

Comment: Thanks, finally I found my problem!!

Comment: This solved my problem. I just needed to add `@EnableWebMvc` to my `@Configuration`-annotated class.

Answer (score 4):

It is necessary to have both `@EnableWebMvc`
and `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Answer (score 3):

This might be caused by not having any MVC configuration in the Spring test context. When using something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
```

...then that `test-context.xml` file should also include things like:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean id="..." class=
"org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean id="..."
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean id="..."
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" 
  class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <value>
      json=application/json
      xml=application/xml
    </value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

One can easily test if the above is the problem, with a controller that does not specify anything special (such as: no `produces` in `@RequestMapping`), and hence does not need any content negotiation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFoo() {
    return "bar";
}
```

...with:

```
@Test
public void getFoo() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = 
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
    Assert.assertEquals(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), "bar"); 
}
```

Comment: Spring should be outputting many error messages if that was the case, no?

Comment: I don't think so, @Raedwald. I posted this after running into 406 Unacceptable myself, and then having found the fix. Not sure if I got any stack traces then, but I doubt it. During initialisation, I don't see why Spring would print any errors for the `@RequestMapping` when not knowing yet what requests it would ever get. And during an actual request it would simply not be able to map it; not much errors to print there? Not being able to map the actual request would be the same as requesting an unknown URL, or requesting using an unmapped HTTP method: an HTTP error response without much else?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following code to spring xml to serialize POJO in jackson.

```
<annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in the configuration xml file.

Comment: Appropriate namespace is xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc".

Answer (score 0):

The spring way of doing things is, i think, to use a HttpResponseEntity, or return a modelandview. 
For example :

```
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> getFoo() {
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  String test = "{\"foo\":{\"title\": \"Stack\"}}";
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(test, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

(I'd be interested in any further progress you make as its all pretty new)

Comment: ok I checked that and still get a 406 response. I altered my question to have the `accept` method removed

Comment: tried that as well. The result is the same with `?someparam` and `param("someparam", value)`

Comment: I do not get a response at all but a 406, so no json... but still works if I curl it

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix is to modify the request this way:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/someurl?someparam=somevalue").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect..
```

Comment: I got the same issue and tried the way provided in this thread. But still 406.

Answer (score -1):

I met same problem just now, and is resolved by changing the return type of the Controller to String. 
And return a JSON string instead of an object directly. It does works.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(dto);
```